# How to make a rounded square groupicon instead of a circle groupicon

Tags: java, android

Hello I have a launcher i've been working on and I want to make the folder icon a rounded square like this:[image].

right now its a circle the shape is made via java code no xml is used

here's the code:

```
package com.appname.viewutil;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.launchername.activity.Home;
import com.launchername.util.Tool;

public class GroupIconDrawable extends Drawable{

    private int outlinepad;
    Bitmap[] icons;
    public float iconSize;
    Paint paint;
    Paint paint2;
    Paint paint4;
    private int iconSizeDiv2;
    private float padding;

    private float scaleFactor = 1;

    private boolean needAnimate, needAnimateScale;

    private float sx = 1;
    private float sy = 1 ;

    public GroupIconDrawable(Bitmap[] icons,float size){
        init(icons,size);
    }

    private void init(Bitmap[] icons,float size){
        this.icons = icons;
        this.iconSize = size;
        iconSizeDiv2 = Math.round(iconSize / 2f);
        padding = iconSize /25f;

        this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setAlpha(150);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        this.paint4 = new Paint();
        paint4.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint4.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint4.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint4.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        outlinepad = Tool.dp2px(2, Home.launcher);
        paint4.setStrokeWidth(outlinepad);

        this.paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    public void popUp(){
        sy = 1;
        sx = 1;
        needAnimate = true;
        needAnimateScale = true;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public void popBack(){
        needAnimate = false;
        needAnimateScale = false;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        if (needAnimateScale){
            scaleFactor = Tool.clampFloat(scaleFactor-0.09f,0.5f,1f);
        }else {
            scaleFactor = Tool.clampFloat(scaleFactor+0.09f,0.5f,1f);
        }

        canvas.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor,iconSize/2,iconSize/2);

        Path clipp = new Path();

        clipp.addCircle(iconSize / 2,iconSize / 2,iconSize / 2-outlinepad, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipp, Region.Op.REPLACE);

        canvas.drawCircle(iconSize / 2, iconSize / 2, iconSize / 2-outlinepad,paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(icons[0],null,new RectF(padding,padding, iconSizeDiv2-padding, iconSizeDiv2-padding),paint2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icons[1],null,new RectF(iconSizeDiv2+padding,padding,iconSize-padding, iconSizeDiv2-padding),paint2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icons[2],null,new RectF(padding, iconSizeDiv2+padding, iconSizeDiv2-padding,iconSize-padding),paint2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icons[3],null,new RectF(iconSizeDiv2+padding, iconSizeDiv2+padding,iconSize-padding,iconSize-padding),paint2);

        canvas.clipRect(0,0,iconSize,iconSize, Region.Op.REPLACE);

        canvas.drawCircle(iconSize / 2, iconSize / 2, iconSize/2-outlinepad,paint4);
        canvas.restore();

        if (needAnimate){
            paint2.setAlpha(Tool.clampInt(paint2.getAlpha()-25,0,255));
            invalidateSelf();
        }else if (paint2.getAlpha() != 255){
            paint2.setAlpha(Tool.clampInt(paint2.getAlpha()+25,0,255));
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {}

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {return PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;}
}
```

any ideas on how to make it a rounded square like in the picture?

any help would be awesome!

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the calls to addCircle and drawCircle with the appropriate RoundRect functions-  addRoundRect and drawRoundRect.

Comment: thanks for the reply can you possibly give me a code example? Thanks in advance!